# createBrowserRouter remounts whole page when context variable changes state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context

My entire site is wrapped inside a context to handle global variables. This used to work with `<BrowserRouter>`. When a variable changed it made everything to refresh but not remount. Might be innefficient but it worked. The reason why I switched to `createBrowserRouter` is that it can use the basic functionality of `<ScrollRestoration />` which is not default for some reason. The problem now is that my whole page remounts every time context variable changes meaning all `useEffect`s with empty dependecy arrays get fired. How can I wrap my site in a context without everything remounting when a context variable changes? Also why does this happen with `createBrowserRouter` but not with `<BrowserRouter>`?

My App.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import User from './pages/User'
import Header from './components/Header'
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import style from './global.module.css'
import { GlobalContext } from './GlobalContext'
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Outlet, ScrollRestoration } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const [loggedInAs, setLoggedInAs] = useState(null)
  const [loginIsOpen, setLoginIsOpen] = useState(false)
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true)
  const [loggedInPfp, setLoggedInPfp] = useState(null)

  function Layout() {
    return (
      <div className={style.siteWrapper}>
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{
          loggedInAs,
          setLoggedInAs,
          loginIsOpen,
          setLoginIsOpen,
          isLogin,
          setIsLogin,
          loggedInPfp,
          setLoggedInPfp
        }}>
          <Header />
          <div className={style.content}>
            <Outlet />
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
        <ScrollRestoration />
      </div>
    )
  }

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      element: <Layout />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <Home />
        },
        {
          path: "/user/:username",
          element: <User />
        },
        {
          path: "/try",
          element: <User />
        },
        {
          path: "/*",
          element: <NotFound />
        }
      ]
    }
  ])


  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  )
}

export default App
```

Example page/component:

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '../GlobalContext'

export default function ExampleComponent() {

  const { setLoggedInAs, setLoggedInPfp } = useContext(GlobalContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("This gets fired every time GlobalContext changes")
    //It should only fire on the initial render.
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that each time your `App` component is re-rendered, it invokes `createBrowserRouter` which creates a new router.

`createBrowserRouter` is not designed to be called inside a component. You can see in the docs [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview).

You can change your logic to something similar

```js
function Layout() {
    const [loggedInAs, setLoggedInAs] = useState(null)
    const [loginIsOpen, setLoginIsOpen] = useState(false)
    const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true)
    const [loggedInPfp, setLoggedInPfp] = useState(null)
    
    return (
      <div className={style.siteWrapper}>
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{
          loggedInAs,
          setLoggedInAs,
          loginIsOpen,
          setLoginIsOpen,
          isLogin,
          setIsLogin,
          loggedInPfp,
          setLoggedInPfp
        }}>
          <Header />
          <div className={style.content}>
            <Outlet />
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
      <ScrollRestoration />
    </div>
  )
}
// move this outside the scope of your component.
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: "/user/:username",
        element: <User />
      },
      {
        path: "/try",
        element: <User />
      },
      {
        path: "/*",
        element: <NotFound />
      }
    ]
  }
])

function App() {

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  )
}
```